# Mosaic-Decisions: different types of parameters

Tags: mosaic-decisions

What different types of parameters do mosaic decision provide?What is the difference between input, calculated, sql and global variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mosaic has two types of parameters:

**1. System Parameters** - These parameters are auto-generated by the mosaic and are passed to hooks and schedule for further use. User cannot edit the values of these parameters. Following are the available system parameters:
a.  lastSuccessfulRunDate
b.  lastRunDate
c.  instanceId
d.  current Time
e.  object Name
f.  Username
g.  User-defined Parameters

**2. User Parameter -** These parameters are defined by an user during the configuration of a flow and can be used in flows as per defined or calculated values. User-defined parameters include:
a.  Input
b.  Calculated
c.  SQL
d.  Global

---

**Difference between Input, Calculated, SQL and Global -**

**1. Input Parameter -** The Input parameter are the parameters that can be used in any flow nodes, hooks, scheduler and can be edited and deleted as and when required.

**2. Calculated Parameter -** The calculated parameters are the parameters whose values are calculated based on the expression user define.

**3. SQL Parameter -** These parameters are used when there is a need to fetch values from records using SQL queries. Mosaic supports Databases like Oracle, SQL, Snowflake, Postgres and SQL Server

**4. Global Parameter -** These parameters are just as input parameters but these parameters unlike input parameters  can be used across the platform. These parameters are defined at Manager Persona and can be added into the flow just like other parameters.

Note - Global Parameters cannot be edited through flows. User will have to edit it through Mosaic Manager and the updated value will get reflected in all the flows the parameter is used.

For more details please refer below link to Mosaic User Help Document -
https://mosaic.ga.lti-mosaic.com/usermanual/parameter.html

Hope this is helpful :)